# why i can't declare a generic form

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

what im trying to do is basically declare a form like this:

```
TFormCRUDBase<T : class> = class(TFormLayoutBase, MVP.Intf.CRUD.ICRUDView<T>)
{ ... }
end;
```

the compiler doesn't accuse any error or warning messages if this feature is allowed or not, anyway but when i try to add some controls in the designer i get this message

```
Declaration of class TFormCRUDBase is missing or incorrect.
```

so the question is why the syntax allow me to use and the IDE simply kicks me away.

thx in advance

Comment: Declaration of the class must be closed be `end` keyword.

Comment: maybe i wasn't clear, there's more things added to the class like fields and methods, i just put it the declaration here. i modified so it could be more legible.

Comment: As Davis says: The form designer does not support generic types. But you can make a wotk arround by letting your Form inheriting a non generic class. I can make a solution for you if you want

Comment: @JensBorrisholt yes, can you please eloborate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply put, the form designer does not support generic types.

The compiler is fine with generic types. You can build the UI, add controls etc. with run time code. But the form designer does not support generic types.

Comment: my god, this is so frustrating, sometimes i really can't understand delphi. why they provide such a feature syntatically speaking but doesn't handle the changes it needs to be made in the IDE for such a feature be compatible.

Comment: Well, I guess that the designers consider that `TForm` descendents are not the main candidate for the use of generics. Which is probably reasonable. Making .dfm files support genericity would, I guess, involve quite a bit of work. I posit that the designers weighed up the pros and cons and decided to expend effort elsewhere. Frustrating for you.

Comment: i can agree with the fact that they decided to put effors elsewhere, i don't agree at all is the discrepancy between compiler x IDE, i mean, in this case the IDE should warning me that isn't allowed or not supported and not throw some vague generic exception. so in the end i have a compiler saying everything is ok and in the other hand the IDE saying it is not.

Comment: I guess what the designers would say is that the IDE will never generate the .pas code for a generic form. You went and modified the IDE generated form code. That's probably the argument that they would make. I'm guessing. It would have been helpful if the IDE just gave you a definitive message saying that generics were not supported though. Then you'd know and would not spend time trying to make it work.

Comment: yeah, it would help greatly. anyway thx for the help and discusion

Comment: I guess the fact that the IDE uses RTTI to find out stuff about classes and to display values also plays a role. RTTI for a generic type is not so easy,

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Is that so? As far as I was aware, generics were well supported by RTTI

Comment: Hmmm... I remember having had serious problems.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis i have to agree with David, the RTTI has full support for generic, this is really about the "BY DESIGN" argument, i really don't like this sentence couse usually is used by devs when they don't want to put the needed efforts to make something work. like David said maybe the changes they need to make in their dfm support would by imense.

Comment: @kabstergo - "used by devs when they don't want" is most likely incorrect. Professional software development is not something that happens at the whim of some random dev. In this case, I suspect not many customers asked for support for generics in forms in the IDE designer...

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera i didn't insinuate that it was what happened in this paticular case, my argument here is that "by design" tends to be convinient sometimes.

Comment: @kabstergo: It is not so much "convenience" (implying laziness), but often simply "it doesn't pay to implement this because it may take a lot of time and/or there is hardly any demand". In other words, it is often a solid business decision not to do everything possible, but to do only what makes (business) sense. Think of YAGNI.

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera i agree with everything you said, its just not that easy the handle this design limitations throughout the years. i can't really count how many times we get our faces into this walls

Answer (score 2):

You asked for a work arround. The solurion are simple, yet not elegant. You have to make at strong type class, and make you form inhirited from that.

First I make some dummy types:

```
type
  ICRUDView<T> = Interface
   function GetObject : T;
  end;

  TMyObject = class
    function Time: String;
  end;
```

and a Simple implementation:

```
{ TMyObject }

function TMyObject.Time: String;
begin
  Result := TimeToStr(now);
end;

procedure TForm5.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Caption := Self.GetObject.Time;
end;
```

Then the strong type from which you have to inherited from:

```
type
  TMyClassForm = class(TForm, ICRUDView<TMyObject>)
  strict private
    InternalObject: TMyObject;
  public
    function GetObject: TMyObject;
  end;
```

and its implementation:

```
{ TMyClassForm }

function TMyClassForm.GetObject: TMyObject;
begin
  if (InternalObject = nil) then
    InternalObject := TMyObject.Create;

  Result := InternalObject;
end;
```

At last you make your form inhirited from your newly created class:

```
  TForm5 = class(TMyClassForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;
```

and use it in your form

```
procedure TForm5.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Caption := Self.GetObject.Time;
end;
```

It's working but its not elegant !